# Implementing highcharts for Coin currency market

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts, bitcoin, scraper

I have coin currency market application and I would like to integrate a graph in it, however I don't know from where data should be taken. Is there some API that I can integrate into my highcharts in order to get graphical representation of values of the coin in the past 7,14,30 days? I have scrapped all data from http://coinmarketcap.com/ but I can't scrap graph because it's canvas. Can you help me with that? Where to search for coin data in the past?

Answer (score 0):

The coinmarketcap site uses json data for the charts. If you look at the network activity in the console, you can see requests for items like:

http://coinmarketcap.com/static/generated_pages/currencies/datapoints/bitcoin-main.json

This contains the json data for the bitcoin chart. However, there does not seem to be any way to specify different time periods.

A quick look around produced this site for bitcoin info (https://bitcoinaverage.com/api). There are lots of links which may help here: able to get prices from here: http://bitcoincharts.com/charts

Answer (score -1):

You can also check yahoo fincancem which allows to get data via API.